# How set specific JRE version on Vscode

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to build a AEM project with maven, but when opening the project with vscode the error
***The compiler compliance specified is 1.8 but a JRE 11 is used*** is show.

I tried configuring the java runtime pressing ctrl + shift + p, but its shows that i'm only using the 1.8 versions
[image]
[image]

How can I set vscode to use the right JRE version?

Answer (score 0):

You can add JDK installations via the setting: `java.configuration.runtimes`

e.g.

```
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\AdoptOpenJDK\\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot",
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-11",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\AdoptOpenJDK\\jdk-11.0.10.9-hotspot"
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here are two modification methods:**

1. Please set the `pom.xml` file for the maven project

```xml
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

2. Modify the `.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` file under the Java project

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=11
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=11
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enablePreviewFeatures=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.forbiddenReference=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.reportPreviewFeatures=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.processAnnotations=enabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.release=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=11
```

Comment: <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>



this is how the pom.xml file is set
and i'm using vscode...not eclipse. not sure where to find ..settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs

Comment: You can modify `pom.xml` as per my answer.